# How to index correctly using Python 3.7 and address associated errors

Tags: pandas, indexing, python-3.7

I have been having issues indexing in Python 3.7. I would greatly appreciate your insights and clarification on this.

I have tried to research and fix this issue but I am not able to understand what I am doing. I would greatly appreciate your help

```
 enroll = pd.read_csv('enrollment_forecast.csv')
 enroll.columns = ['year','roll','unem','hgrad','inc']

 # the correlation between variables
 enroll.corr()

 enroll_data = enroll.ix[:(2,3)].values
 print(enroll_data)

 enroll_target = enroll.ix[:,1].values
 print(enroll_target)

 enroll_data_names = ['unem','hgrad']


Exception has occurred: AssertionError
End slice bound is non-scalar
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `regression` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `pandas`).

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up, Pandas `.ix` index accessor is deprecated.

It's throwing the error error because you are passing it a tuple:

```
 enroll_data = enroll.ix[:(2,3)].values
```

Try passing it a list instead of a tuple:

```
 enroll_data = enroll.ix[:[2,3]].values
```

Comment: I get a new error: TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [[2, 3]] of <class 'list'>

Comment: Try without braces at all: `enroll_data = enroll.ix[:2,3].values`?